# Validate switch for all rows in table view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I have a switch inside table view cell (I have a table view inside table view, in the fist table view I have the label for the question and other table view for the switch with the label for the answer, I load a view from xib), I try to validate when user chose an answer for each of the questions, and validate if the select answer is correct, I have this JSON from de API that tell me if the answer is correct or not

```
"answers": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "answer": "si",
        "isCorrect": false,
    },
    {
         "id": 2,
         "answer": "no",
         "isCorrect": true,
    }
]
```

This is my first view controller where I have my first table view

```
class QUIZViewController: UIViewController {
  
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var tableViewHC: NSLayoutConstraint!
  @IBOutlet weak var continueButton: UIButton!

  
  var challenge : Challenge = Challenge()
  
  var questionsCount : Int = 0
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setTextAndStyles()
    setTableView()
    tableViewHC.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
  }
  
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableViewHC.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
  }

  func setTableView(){
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "QuestionListTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "questionListCell")
    
    
    tableView.isScrollEnabled = false

    continueButton.solid()
    continueButton.isEnabled = false
    continueButton.setTitle("CONTINUAR", for: .normal)
  }

  func validations(){
    // Here I have to validate if user chose an answer for each of the questions, after that I set enable the button continue
  }
  
extension QUIZViewController:  UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    tableViewHC.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    return questionsCount
  }
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "questionListCell", for: indexPath) as! QuestionListTableViewCell
    cell.separatorInset.right = cell.separatorInset.left
    cell.questionLabel.text = "Question"
    cell.setup(answers: challenge.questions?[indexPath.row].answers ?? [Answer]())
    tableViewHC.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    return cell
  }
}
```

This is second table view class where I have the switch with label for the answer

```
extension QuestionListTableViewCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return answers.count
  }
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "answerListCell", for: indexPath) as! AnswerListTableViewCell
    cell.separatorInset.right = cell.separatorInset.left
    cell.answerList.optionLabel.text = answers[indexPath.row].answer
    cell.answerList.optionSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.answerList.optionSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    cell.answerList.optionSwitch.isOn = indexPath.row == selectedSwitchIndex

    return cell
  }

  @objc func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch!){
    guard sender.isOn else {
        return
    }
    selectedSwitchIndex = sender.tag
    print(answers[sender.tag].id)       // this the id for the answer
    print(answers[sender.tag].isCorrect)// this boolean tell me if is correct
    tableView.reloadData()
    
    list.append([answers[sender.tag].id:answers[sender.tag].isCorrect])
  }

}
```

[image]

I think about a solution it could be create a list with the id and boolean then use a callback to validate if user chose an answer for each of the questions and finally check is the answers are correct or not but I am no sure about that, what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: This looks like a ***very*** convoluted way of going about this. First, you would be much better off putting your answers (switch and label) in a `UIStackView` in your cell, rather than a table view in the cell. Then, yes, use either a "callback" closure or protocol/delegate pattern to let your controller know what was selected, at which point your controller should update the data.

Comment: Yes it would be easier with @DonMag approach, but if you want to still achieve with the same I can see two ways 

1) differentiate switches with tag in which indexPath it exist and check state while turning on for all switches. 

2) Maintain nullable array with the same number as your entries and once switch turns on change its value